# SQL want to avoid repeated rows

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a table like this:

```
Employee
| id | name | department |
| 01 | Joe  | Network    |
| 02 | Sam  | Quality    |
| 03 | Mark | Network    |
| 04 | Pete | Quality    |
```

And other table like this:

```
Hours
| id | date    | hours |
| 01 | 1/1/11  | 7     |
| 02 | 1/2/11  | 15    |
| 03 | 1/5/11  | 13    |
| 01 | 1/7/11  | 5     |
| 01 | 1/11/11 | 9     |
| 02 | 1/11/11 | 11    |
| 03 | 1/12/11 | 14    |
| 04 | 1/12/11 | 14    |
```

I want to query this: show the person who achieve the max total hours from each department (sorted from the max to the min)

```
| id | Name | Department | totalhours |
| 03 | Mark | Network    | 27         |
| 02 | Sam  | Quality    | 26         |
```

My current code doesnt work, just showsme the total hours of each person:

```
SELECT e.name, e.department, SUM(h.hours) AS total
FROM employee e JOIN hours h ON e.id = h.id
GROUP BY e.name, e.department
ORDER BY total DESC;
```

What i need to do?

i tried something like this...

```
SELECT e.name, e.department, t.total
FROM (
    SELECT e2.department, SUM(h.hours) AS total
    FROM employee e2 JOIN hours h ON e2.id=h.id 
    GROUP BY e2.department, h.hours
    ) t JOIN employee e JOIN hours h ON e.id=h.id ON e.department = t.department AND t.total = h.hours

ORDER BY t.total DESC;
```

But this shows crazy results ( i think my code is crazy lol)

PLEASE HELP!!
Thanks!!

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are actually using.  Postgres?  Or MySQL?

Comment: its Postgresql sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select id, name, department, total
from
(
SELECT e.id, e.name, e.department, t.total,
rank() over(partition by e.department order by t.total desc) as rnk
FROM (
SELECT id, SUM(hours) AS total
FROM hours
GROUP BY id
) t JOIN employee e ON e.id = t.id
) t
where rnk = 1
order by total desc
```

Comment: that code runs but shows all persons instead just the best from each department..

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: Its better than the older ;) but doesnt sort correctly, isnt sorted i mean.

Comment: you should put in some effort to solve it. I modified the query to include `order by total desc`.

Comment: sorry and too much thanks, i tried some "order by" before the answer. You are the best ;)

Comment: cant upvote your solution but when i achieve the requirements i ll upvote it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This will show more than 1 row for a department if there is a tie. Probably what you do want.

```
    SELECT EachEmp.name, EachEmp.department, MAXES.maxTotal AS total
    FROM (SELECT e.name,    -- sum up each employees totals
                 e.department, 
                 SUM(h.hours) AS total
          FROM employee e 
          JOIN hours h ON e.id = h.id
          GROUP BY e.name, e.department) EachEmp
    JOIN
       (SELECT department, max(total) maxTotal  -- get the maximum emp total for this dept
        FROM (   SELECT e.department, SUM(h.hours) AS total
                 FROM employee e 
                 JOIN hours h ON e.id = h.id
                 GROUP BY e.name, e.department) AS TOTAL -- note we are grouping by e.name
        GROUP BY department) AS MAXES
    ON EachEmp.department = MAXES.department
       AND EachEmp.total = MAXES.maxTotal
    ORDER BY MAXES.maxTotal DESC;
```

Comment: Thank you, that comments are so important to understand every line.

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres, the easiest (and usually the fastest) way to do this is with `distinct on`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (e.name) e.name, e.department, SUM(h.hours) AS total
FROM employee e JOIN
     hours h
     ON e.id = h.id
GROUP BY e.name, e.department
ORDER BY e.name, total DESC;
```